# how to create a row of scrollable text boxes or widgets in flutter inside a ListView?

Tags: dart, flutter

1.Please, can someone tell me how to create a row of text boxes that are scrollable to left or right in flutter inside a ListView. I can see that I am trying to define an infinite width inside a finite width ListView. But, can't figure out any workaround for this one.

the below-mentioned code works absolutely fine if simply comment the scrolldirection property in customscrollview(i.e., change the scrolldirection to vertical). But, i am looking for a horizontal scroll.
I have tried to solve this but no luck.

can someone please help and let me know where i am doing wrong.

2. Also, how can we create or inflate a layout like we do in Android in the flutter?
   I have included a screenshot of layout i am creating for reference:

[image: 1[enter image description here]

I have posted the code below to reproduce the same error;

Regards,
Mahi

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
   import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
       void main(){
       runApp(new AddNewBlock());
       }

 class AddNewBlock extends StatefulWidget{

@override
State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
return new _AddNewBlockState();
    }
  }

   class _AddNewBlockState extends State<AddNewBlock>{


    @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new MaterialApp(
            title: 'Add New Block',
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

  home: new Scaffold(

    body: new ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,

      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 16.0,top: 24.0, bottom: 8.0,
          ),
          child: new Text(
            'Add New Block',
          style: new TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.teal[300],
    ),
          ),
        ),
        new Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, top: 16.0, bottom: 8.0),
          child: new Text ('Block Name'),
        ),

        new Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 8.0, 0.0, 8.0),
          child: new Text ('Block A1',
          style: new TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
          ),),
        ),
        new Divider(color: Colors.grey,),
        new Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, top: 8.0,bottom: 8.0),
          child: new Text('NO. OF FLOORS',
          style: new TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12.0,
          ),
          ),
        ),



       new Container(
                    child: new Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Flexible(
                          child: new CustomScrollView(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            slivers: <Widget>[
                          new SliverPadding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                          sliver: new SliverList(
                            delegate: new SliverChildListDelegate(
                              <Widget>[
                                const Text('this'),
                                const Text('is'),
                                const Text('scroll'),
                                const Text('view'),
                                const Text('inside'),
                                const Text('list'),
                                const Text('view'),
                                const Text('in'),
                                const Text('horizontal'),
                                const Text('direction')
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),





      ],

    ),
  ),


  );
   }
}
```

Comment: I want to put items into new lines, which widget should I use?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I think this is straightforward as long as you put a container of fixed height on your horizontal `ListView`. But maybe I'm not understanding your question. Please post your code and the error message you're getting if this doesn't work.

[image: screenshot]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'dart:collection';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new DemoApp()));
}

class DemoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Nested ListView Example')),
      body: new Center(
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              height: 80.0,
              child: new ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: new List.generate(10, (int index) {
                  return new Card(
                    color: Colors.blue[index * 100],
                    child: new Container(
                      width: 50.0,
                      height: 50.0,
                      child: new Text("$index"),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what the OP is looking for, I think the problem was the way we thought that a horizontal `ListView` must wrap a `Row` widget (to placed the `children` in an horizontal order), hence the error `hasSize!=true`.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply @Collin Jackson. This solves my problem, the only trick I was missing is to specify the height of the container. thanks everyone for their valuable suggestions.

Comment: yes you are right @aziza, we never specified the height of a container and that was causing the problems. But, thanks again to Collin Jackson on getting back to us.

Comment: How could we target every item separately to have a different text?

Answer (score 36):

I have done this to make my Row widget scrollable:

```
Text("Debilidades",
    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0),
  child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: pokemon.weaknesses == null
          ? <Widget>[
              Text(
                "No tiene debilidades",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
              )
            ]
          : pokemon.weaknesses
              .map((weakness) => FilterChip(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  label: Text(
                    weakness,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),

                  onSelected: (b) {}))
              .toList()),
),
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my god, so easily...! :D

Comment: Easy and sexy!!

Answer (score 31):

For a row/column to scroll you can simply use the `SingleChildScrollView` feature and mention the direction as required.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    child: Row(
        children: [
            //provide all the things u want to horizontally scroll here
        ]
    ),
);
```

Comment: very simple and powerfull!

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox( // Horizontal ListView
        height: 100,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 20,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              width: 100,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              color: Colors.blue[(index % 9) * 100],
              child: Text(index.toString()),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox( // Vertical ListView
        height: 200,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 20,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              color: Colors.orange[(index % 9) * 100],
              child: Text(index.toString()),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Note: For simplicity I didn't refactor the two `ListView` in a single Widget

#### Output

[image]

Comment: Which widget can give me power to transfer items into new row?

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to do this by using `ListView.builder()`

Here is the full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Scroll on the Horizon"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: new ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text("Let ", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),),
                new Text("me ", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
                new Text("scroll ", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
                new Text("horizontally ",
                    style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.orange)),
                new Text("Let ", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),),
                new Text("me ", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
                new Text("scroll ", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
                new Text("horizontally ",
                    style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.orange)),
                new Text("Let ", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),),
                new Text("me ", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
                new Text("scroll ", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
                new Text("horizontally ",
                    style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.orange)),
                new Text("Let ", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),),
                new Text("me ", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
                new Text("scroll ", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
                new Text("horizontally ",
                    style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.orange)),

              ],

            );
          },


        ));
  }

}
```

Do not forget to set `scrollDirection` property to `Axis.horizontal`, since it is defaulted to the `vertical` value.

Comment: Hi @aziza Thank you very much for your reply . But the solution is not working for me as you can see, I need to embed this scrolling Row inside a ListView with a scrolldirection as vertical. Please let me know if you know anyway to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Aha, I think what we should be looking at here is [NestedScrollView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html), I will give it a try myself later.

Answer (score 1):

I made that using a Row widget wrapped with a SingleChildScrollView with horizontal scroll direction, then, I wrapped my row widgets with another row in order to add a sized box widget to make the spacing between those widgets.