# Force ListView to shrink to contain children

Tags: dart, flutter

The most similar question I could find was ['how to create a row of scrollable text boxes or widgets in flutter inside a ListView?'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46226849/9431247), however their solution was just to assign a height to the ListView's Container:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Define a 'main' function to run when our app starts
void main() {
  var app = new MaterialApp(
    home: new SafeArea(
      left: false,
      top: true,
      right: false,
      bottom: false,
      child: new Scaffold(
        body: new Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          height: 50.0,
          child: new ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Icon(Icons.check_circle, size: 50.0),
              new Icon(Icons.add, size: 50.0),
              new Icon(Icons.add, size: 50.0),
              new Icon(Icons.add, size: 50.0),
              new Icon(Icons.add, size: 50.0),
              new Icon(Icons.add, size: 50.0),
              new Icon(Icons.add, size: 50.0),
              new Icon(Icons.add, size: 50.0),
              new Icon(Icons.add, size: 50.0),
              new Icon(Icons.add, size: 50.0),
              new Icon(Icons.add, size: 50.0),
              new Icon(Icons.add, size: 50.0),
              new Icon(Icons.close, size: 50.0),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: new Text("Hello")
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );

  runApp(app);
}
```

According to [Julien Louage](https://medium.com/jlouage/container-de5b0d3ad184), a Container expands to fill its parent unless a child is added, in which case, it will shrink to accommodate the dimensions of the child. If you were to remove Container's height property, it will go back to filling its parent, as if it didn't contain a child.

The reasonable conclusion is that ListView is causing the issue; ListView wants to be as big as it can, and there is no apparent way to change this.

Other widgets like Row have methods of shrinking to contain children but ListView does not? To see an example of this as well as Container's sizing convention, remove some Icons to avoid pixel overflow and make the following changes:

```
//height: 50.0,
child: new Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
//child: new ListView(
//  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
```

So how can I make ListView shrink to contain children (like Row can w/ CrossAxisAlignment.center) w/o setting the height of the Container? There should be a way!

Comment: Are you looking for `shrinkWrap` property of `ListView` ?

Comment: @Rémi Rousselet No, I already checked that out, the flutter docs define it as: "Whether the extent of the scroll view in the scrollDirection should be determined by the contents being viewed". I need a solution for the cross axis, not the main axis.

Comment: That is impossible. Items are lazy loaded, the width can't be known

Comment: I think you meant height, in my case? So what you're saying is that if a shrinkWrap for cross axis existed, it might result in the height of the ListView having to change as the user scrolled through the list? That is probably why they chose not to implement the feature.

Comment: Yeah height sorry. Exactly, this is the reason it doesn't exist. If you have a limited number of items, consider using `Row` into a `SingleChildScrollView`. Else limit your elements size on the list cross-axis

Answer (score 0):

Wrap listview into a container and set the size you want.